# Where can I find firefox sync server?

Tags: firefox, sync

I had configured firefox sync server for testing. Where can I find the server side contents (Is there site I can login and see what are all got synced ? ). Something similar to UbuntuOne, where you can manage content online by logging in.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can look at the 'real' firefox sync server's contents, but you could build and install your own server using the code [here](https://hg.mozilla.org/services/server-full) and point your firefox to it?

Comment: I got this link. But, It gives to way to purge all data. 


https://account.services.mozilla.com/sync/

Comment: Yes it lets you purge but won't let you look at it.